# Cross platform build script that can call MSBuild or Xbuild depending on environment?

Tags: c#, python, scripting, msbuild, mono

I have a simple .Net console app which has only framework dependencies. It can compile fine with either MSBuild on windows or Mono/XBuild on linux. It is part of a larger project, which has a python build script. Is there any simple way to determine the most suitable build engine (msbuild/xbuild) and use that?

In other words, I have a 'build.py' and I want that to call xbuild or msbuild as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Far easier would be to write a small shell script for Linux or OSX that ran xbuild but was called msbuild. The arguments are the same I think.

Comment: True - but I suppose this would mean ensuring that for e.g %WinDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5 and '.' was in the $PATH, so that the single command 'msbuild' would succeed on both platforms. Unless I am missing something?

Comment: @FrepD-Oronge yes, that is correct. But I think that is far easier to do in your script (the script can add things to the path)